# Where to download the assembly that contains NHibernate.Caches.Prevalence.PrevalenceCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.Prevalence?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, caching

In the nhibernate doco is states that to use the prevalence cache use the provider class “NHibernate.Caches.Prevalence.PrevalenceCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.Prevalence” https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache

Where do I go to doanload the assembly that contains this type?

According to the doco (https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/caches.html) it can be obtained from http://bbooprevalence.sourceforge.net/ . But I downloaded Bamboo.Prevalence-1.4.4.4 and could not find any cache assemblies.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out it is part of NHContrib

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/